# Sending user input from android alert to custom alert xamarin

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

So, I'm working on a Xamarin project. I'm working on an application that sends helpful pop ups within the application to the user(tips for example). The user can set the time when they receive this pop up within the application(for example, they can receive pop ups at 19:00 or at 12:00). I created a custom class for this called Alert. The IOS version of the application is working as intended

However, since the stock android alerts didn't had any way to add input fields in it, I had to create a special view for this alert. The main problem that I'm encountering right now is that the user input from the custom view is not sent to the Xamarin forms alert.

Android Code:

```
public class Alert : IAlert
{
    public static readonly int AlertWidth = Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone ? 270 : 320;

    class AlertDialogFragment : DialogFragment
    {
        public string Title;
        public string Body;
        public View Content;
        public List<AlertButton> Buttons;
        public Func<Task> tcs;


        public Dialog AndroidCustomAlert(Activity activ)
        {
            Android.Views.LayoutInflater inflater = Android.Views.LayoutInflater.From(activ);
            Android.Views.View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.AlertDialogLayout, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activ);
            builder.SetView(view);
            Android.Widget.TextView title = view.FindViewById<Android.Widget.TextView>(Resource.Id.Login);
            title.Text = Title;

            Android.Widget.TextView body = view.FindViewById<Android.Widget.TextView>(Resource.Id.pincodeText);
            body.Text = Body;

            Android.Widget.Timepicker timepicker= view.FindViewById<Android.Widget.Timepicker >(Resource.Id.timepicker);
            Android.Widget.Button btnPositive = view.FindViewById<Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.btnLoginLL);
            Android.Widget.Button btnNegative = view.FindViewById<Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.btnClearLL);
            Android.Widget.Button btnNeutral = view.FindViewById<Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.btnNeutral);


            //Checks if there are no buttons, and if there aren't any, creates a neutral one
            if (Buttons == null || Buttons.Count == 0)
            {
                btnPositive.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;
                btnNegative.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;
                btnNeutral.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Visible;
                timepicker.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;

                Buttons = new List<AlertButton> {
                new AlertButton {
                    Text = "Oké",
                    IsPreferred = true,
                    Action = () => false
                }
            };
                btnNeutral.Text = Buttons.First().Text;
                btnNeutral.Click += delegate
                {
                    CommandsForButtons(Buttons.First());
                };
            }


            //Positive button feedback
            btnPositive.Text = Buttons.Last().Text;
            btnPositive.Click += delegate
            {
                CommandsForButtons(Buttons.Last());
            };

            //Negative button feedback
            btnNegative.Text = Buttons.First().Text;
            btnNegative.Click += delegate
            {
                CommandsForButtons(Buttons.First());
            };

            builder.SetCancelable(false);
            return builder.Create();
        }

        public void CommandsForButtons(AlertButton button)
        {
            var command = new Command(async () =>
            {
                var ab = button;
                var cont = true;
                if (ab.Action != null)
                    cont = ab.Action();
                if (ab.ActionAsync != null)
                {
                    cont = cont && await ab.ActionAsync();
                }
                if (!cont)
                {
                    Dismiss();
                }
            });

            command.Execute(this);
        }

        public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var test = AndroidCustomAlert(Activity);
            //test.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            return test;
        }

    }

    public async Task Show(string title, string body, View content, List<AlertButton> buttons)
    {

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

        var adf = new AlertDialogFragment
        {
            Title = title,
            Body = body,
            Content = content,
            Buttons = buttons
        };
        var FragmentManager = ((Activity)Forms.Context).FragmentManager;

        FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        //Remove fragment else it will crash as it is already added to backstack
        Fragment prev = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("alert");
        if (prev != null)
        {
            ft.Remove(prev);
        }

        ft.AddToBackStack(null);

        adf.Show(ft, "alert");

        //await tcs.Task;

        return;
    }

}
```

Alert Class:

```
public interface IAlert
{
    Task Show(string title, string body, View content, List<AlertButton> buttons);
}

public static class Alert
{
    public static async Task Show(string title, string body, View content = null, params AlertButton[] buttons)
    {
        var enabled = MainApp.BackEnabled;
        MainApp.BackEnabled = false;
        await DependencyService.Get<IAlert>().Show(title, body, content, buttons.ToList());
        MainApp.BackEnabled = enabled;
    }
}

public class AlertButton 
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsDestructive { get; set; }
    public bool IsPreferred { get; set; }
    public Func<bool> Action { get; set; }
    public Func<Task<bool>> ActionAsync { get; set; }

}}
```

IOS code:

```
public class iOSAlert : IAlert
{
    public static readonly int AlertWidth = Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone ? 270 : 320;

    public async Task Show(string title, string body, View content, List<AlertButton> buttons)
    {
        if (buttons == null || buttons.Count == 0)
        {
            buttons = new List<AlertButton> {
                new AlertButton {
                    Text = "Oké",
                    IsPreferred = true,
                    Action = () => false
                }
            };
        }

        Func<Task> dismiss = null;

        var captionSize = (double)StyleKit.PhoneDarkLabelStyles.Caption.Setters.First(s => s.Property == Label.FontSizeProperty).Value;
        var titleSize = (double)StyleKit.PhoneDarkLabelStyles.Title.Setters.First(s => s.Property == Label.FontSizeProperty).Value;

        var top = new StackLayout {
            Padding = new Thickness(15, 20, 15, 20),
            Spacing = 3,
            Children = {
                new Label {
                    Text = title,
                    Style = StyleKit.PhoneDarkLabelStyles.Title,
                    FontSize = Math.Max(16, titleSize),
                    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
                },
                new Label {
                    Text = body,
                    Style = StyleKit.PhoneDarkLabelStyles.Body,
                    //FontSize = ,
                    FontSize = Math.Max(14, captionSize),
                    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
                } ,
                new ContentView {
                    Padding = new Thickness(0,5,0,-10),
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
                    Content = content
                } 
            }
        };

        var buttonViews = buttons.Select(ab => new Button {
            FontSize = Math.Max(16, titleSize),
            Text = ab.Text,
            FontAttributes = ab.IsPreferred ? FontAttributes.Bold : FontAttributes.None,
            TextColor = ab.IsDestructive ? Color.Red : Color.Default,
            Command = new Command(async () => {
                var cont = true;
                if (ab.Action != null)
                    cont = ab.Action();
                if (ab.ActionAsync != null)
                    cont = cont && await ab.ActionAsync();
                if (!cont)
                    await dismiss();
            })
        }).ToList();

        var grid = new Grid {
            RowDefinitions = {
                new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
                new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto }
            },
            ColumnSpacing = 0,
            RowSpacing = 0
        };
        buttons.ForEach(button => {
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(
                new ColumnDefinition {
                    Width = AlertWidth / buttonViews.Count
                }
            );
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < buttonViews.Count; i++)
        {
            grid.Children.Add(new BorderView {
                BorderColor = Color.FromRgba(0,0,0,0.2),
                Thickness = new Thickness(0, 1, (i + 1 < buttonViews.Count) ? 1 : 0, 0)
            }, i, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(buttonViews[i], i, 1);
        }
        grid.Children.Add(top, 0, buttons.Count, 0, 1);

        var box = new Frame {
            WidthRequest = AlertWidth,
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgba(1,1,1,0.96),
            Padding = 0,
            Content = grid
        };
        var outer = new AbsoluteLayout {
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgba(0,0,0,0.65),
            Opacity = 0,
            Children = { box }
        };
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(box, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(box,
            new Rectangle(0.5, 0.5, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize));

        var page = new ContentPage {
            Content = /* new ScrollView { Content = */ outer // }
        };

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        var topVC = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
        while (topVC.PresentedViewController != null) {
            topVC = topVC.PresentedViewController;
        }

        var vc = page.CreateViewController();
        topVC.Add(vc.View);
        var innerView = vc.View.Subviews[0].Subviews[0];
        vc.View.RemoveFromSuperview();

        dismiss = async () => {
            dismiss = async () => {};
            await outer.FadeTo(0, 50);
            innerView.RemoveFromSuperview();
            tcs.SetResult(null);
        };

        topVC.Add(innerView);
        await outer.FadeTo(1, 100);
        await tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Example of alert with Entry:

```
await Alert.Show(
            "Time" + (isEdit ? "Edit" : "toevoegen"),
            "Fill the time in you want to receive an notification.",
            tp,
            cancelButton,
            new AlertButton
            {
                Text = "Save",
                IsPreferred = true,
                Action = () =>
                {
                    var newTime = tp.Time.MinutesOnly();
                    if (!isEdit || newTime != time)
                    {
                        if (isEdit) scheduler.RemoveTime(time);
                        scheduler.AddTime(newTime);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        );
```

I have the following question:
How can I sent the user information to the Xamarin Forms alert **without** changing the Alert class?

Kind Regards,

Frederick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, you can use 
Task Show(string title, string body, View content, List buttons);
To get the result, in Android project you can use TaskCompletionSource to wait user input.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx

Otherwise, you can use acr.userdialogs.prompt to do the same thing.
https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/blob/master/docs/prompt.md

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer! However, the TaskCompletionSource doesn't sent the user input to the Alert in the Android version. I placed it in the Show() method of the Android version of alert, is this the right place?

Comment: You almost get there,1. Put Completionshource into Alter class in Android code, 2. pass this Completionshource into AlertDialogFragment. 3. when clicking 'OK button' set Completionshource result as TextInput. 4. wait for this Completionshource in show function.

Comment: Alright, Got it working! It was a combination of the TaskCompletionSource not implemented and the Content not properly set. I shall accept your answer, thanks for the help!